# My pipeline is failing a with an "groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException' error.No idea what is the issue

Tags: json, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, ucd

Error:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: master for class: groovy.lang.Binding
16:31:47    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
16:31:47    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:271)
16:31:47    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$7.call(Checker.java:353)
16:31:47    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:357)
16:31:47    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
16:31:47    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
16:31:47    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:333)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:29)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
16:31:47    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:71)
16:31:47    at ***cps.transform***(Native Method)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
16:31:47    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor335.invoke(Unknown Source)
16:31:47    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
16:31:47    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
16:31:47    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)

```
pipeline 
{
    agent {label 'maven36'} 
    environment
   {
      BUILD_USER_ID="${specificCause.userId[0]}"
      GIT_CREDS=credentials('DEVOPS')
      encodedPass=URLEncoder.encode(GIT_CREDS_PSW, "UTF-8")
      user="$GIT_CREDS_USR"
          
    } 
    stages      
    {
        
         stage('Clone') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}")
                {
                    git credentialsId: 'DEVOPS', url: gitUrl
                }
            } 
        } 
                    
        stage('Build') 
        {
            steps 
            {
                echo "================Build===================="
                
                dir("${env.WORKSPACE}")
                {
                        sh 'ls -lrt'
                        
                }
                sh 'echo "======Build success======"'
            }
        }   
        stage('Publish Artifacts to UCD') {
            steps {
                script {
                    node (master) {
                    try {
                        echo "Publishing"
                        withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: "${UCD_CREDENTIAL_ID}", usernameVariable: 'UCD_USER', passwordVariable: 'UCD_PASSWORD')]){
                        step([$class: 'UCDeployPublisher',
                            siteName: 'UCD - Production',
                             altUser: [
                                        altPassword: hudson.util.Secret.fromString(env.UCD_PASSWORD),
                                        altUsername: env.UCD_USER
                            ],
                            component: [
                                $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.VersionHelper$VersionBlock',
                                componentName: " EUX0_DS",
                                
                                delivery: [
                                    $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeliveryHelper$Push',
                                    pushVersion: "${UCD_PUBLISH_VERSION}",
                                    baseDir: "${WORKSPACE}/toucd",
                                    fileIncludePatterns: '**/*',
                                    fileExcludePatterns: '',
                                    pushProperties: '',
                                    pushDescription: '',
                                    pushIncremental: false
                                ]
                            ]
                        ])
                        }
                    }

                    catch (Exception errorlogs) {
                        println(errorlogs)
                        currentBuild.result = 'FAILED'
                        echo "Stage Status is ${currentBuild.result}"
                        error 'Exiting CI Pipeline'
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }       
        stage('Deploy to UCD') {

        steps {

            script{
                
              
                withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'DEVOPS', passwordVariable: 'password', usernameVariable: 'username')]) {

                try  {

                    hudson.util.Secret pass = hudson.util.Secret.fromString("${env.password}")
                    
                    //env.ProjectName=sh(script: 'echo $JOB_BASE_NAME | sed "s/DN00_//"' | tr -d "\r\n" ', returnStdout: true)
                    //env.Deploy_env=sh(script: 'DEPLOY_DEV=DEV;DEPLOY_QA=QA;ROLLBACK_DEV=DEV;ROLLBACK_QA=QA;BUGFIX_QA=DEV;eval ENVR=\'\$\'$TASK; echo $ENVR | tr -d "\r\n" ', returnStdout: true)
                 //env.Deploy_process=sh(script: 'ROLLBACK_DEV=Rollback_"${env.ProjectName}";DEPLOY_DEV=Deploy_"${env.ProjectName}";DEPLOY_QA=Deploy_"${env.ProjectName}";ROLLBACK_QA=Rollback_"${env.ProjectName}";BUGFIX_QA=Deploy_"${env.ProjectName}";eval PRO=\'\$\'$TASK; echo $PRO | tr -d "\r\n"', returnStdout: true)
                step([

                $class: 'UCDeployPublisher',

                siteName: 'UCD - Production',

                altUser: [

                   $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.UCDeployPublisher$UserBlock',

                   altUsername: "${env.username}",

                   altPassword: pass

                ],

                deploy: [

                    $class: 'com.urbancode.jenkins.plugins.ucdeploy.DeployHelper$DeployBlock',

                    deployApp: "EUX0_Retail_Credit_Operational_Datastore_DATASTAGE",

                    deployEnv: "DEV",
                                  
                    deployProc: "Deploy",

                    deployVersions: "${EUX0_DS}:${JENKINS_VER_CD}-${BUILD_NUMBER}",

                    deployOnlyChanged: false

                ]

                  ])

                currentBuild.result = 'SUCCESS'

                } catch (Exception e)  {

                     throw(e)

                     }


                    }
                
                }

        }

    }
    
  }

  post { 
        always { 
            deleteDir()
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use single quote for the node name `node (master) -> node ('master')`